# SAPUI5 Aggregation for sap.m.Bar issue

Tags: sapui5

in my dialog I want to include a custom header or subheader with a button. My view.xml looks like this:

```
 <mvc:FragmentDefinition
   xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core" xmlns:m="sap.m" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout" 
   xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form">
  <m:Dialog id="dialog3ID" title="{i18n>Deliveries}" contentHeight="auto">
      <m:customHeader>
        <m:Bar>
        <contentLeft>
             <m:Button id="Btn_Back" iconDensityAware="false" text="
             {i18n>Back}" type="Emphasized" width="10%" enabled="true" visible="true" press="onCancelD3" />
        </contentLeft>
        </m:Bar>
    </m:customHeader>
    <m:content> 
      ......
    </m:content>
```

The error message I get is Cannot add direct child without default aggregation defined for control sap.m.Bar

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help,
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use sap.m.Bar in aggregation for [sap.m.Dialog](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Dialog/aggregations). You should use [sap.m.IBar](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.IBar.html) instead. So change:

```
<m:Bar>
```

to:

```
<m:IBar>
```

The same for:

```
</m:Bar>
```